# Let Someone Know File is Selected for Upload Using File_Field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload

I have a rails app that allows the user to upload a file using the paperclip gem.  I don't want to upload the image straight to s3; but, want a traditional uploader that's going through the file_field helper.  If I'm using this approach, how can I let a user know that an image has been selected for upload before they hit the save button on the page and upload the image (and rest of data with it)?  Is this something that can be done w/ JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to notify user before form submission. Check example below. It prevents form to be submitted, if file is not selected. If file was selected, form will be submitted in regular way.

```js
$('#upload_image').submit(function(event) {
    var filename = $('#image').val();
    if (filename === undefined || filename === '') {
        $('#notification').html('File is not selected!');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="upload_image" action="/images" method="POST">
    <p id="notification"></p>
    <input type="file" id="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```